Compare classification performance of dataset subsets based on factors
Let's say I have a dataset like this on which I want to perform classification:



id
feature
class
factor




1
...
1
A


2
...
1
B


3
...
2
A


4
...
2
B


$\vdots$






How can I compare the performance of a model given the values of the factor?
For instance, let's say I'm using a handwritten digit dataset with a factor being if the person is left or right-handed. How could I compare if the model does better with left-handed or right-handed data?
